# Remove the Unfortunately the app has stopped message in android(Not its cause, but message itself)

Tags: android

Is there any way I can get rid of this message despite the app being stopped due to any exception? 
My app(background service) is designed in such a way that it always restarts itself within 1 mins in case it gets killed. So even if it gets stopped, it would be restarted again, with no negative impact. Hence that message would unnecessarily annoy/worry the users.

As the app works fine on my device, but on other's device, its giving that message once or twice a day. I have no way to read the logs and check whats going on. I have placed the try/catch block everywhere. And the code is too complex to dig into again and check whats wrong. In short, I don't want to get rid of the "cause" off the message. But the "message" itself. Is it at all possible?

So How do I get rid of android OS showing that message even if it has "stopped"?

Comment: Try using try catch..

Comment: Its everywhere. @Lal . I want to get rid of message, not the "cause" of the message. Is is at all possible?

Comment: You can't. It's a code in the OS, and if your app is stopped, it is 'stopped,' it has no function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So even if it gets stopped, it would be restarted again, with no negative impact

There is no way to know whether or not there is a "negative impact" until the source of the problem is found.

> I have no way to read the logs and check whats going on. I

Use crash logging frameworks like [ACRA](http://acra.ch/) to collect stack traces from production apps.

> And the code is too complex to dig into again and check whats wrong.

Use the crash logs from crash logging frameworks like ACRA to identify the source of the problem.

> Is it at all possible?

Read the documentation for your chosen crash logging framework and see [what the options are for user notification regarding such crashes](https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/BasicSetup#is-that-all). Some, like ACRA, will offer a "silent" mode where the crash is logged but without informing the users of that crash.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, you could set up your own [Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler%28java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler%29)